# Equation with complex coefficients with roots corners of parallelogram

Tags: complex-numbers

The complete problem is this: the roots of the equation $z^4-4z^3+(3-2i)z^2 + (2+4i)z + 6-8i = 0$ lie in the corners of a parallelogram in the complex plane. Solve the equation.

This is a problem I saw, and tried to solve it for fun. I am so stuck, and would appreciate any hints. This is not a homework problem, so be as cryptic as you want. I heard something about the midpoint of the parallelogram and translating it to the origin, giving a possible change of variables to make the equation easier, but I can't seem to put the pieces together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: finding roots means finding values for the unknown (z here) such that the equation vanishes (equal to zero). Complex roots are equal to zero when both RE and IM parts are zero.

Comment: Use http://gradestack.com/CBSE-Class-9th-Complete/Quadrilterals/Theorem-4-In-a/14902-2953-4006-study-wtw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are the roots, then $\frac {z_1 + z_2} 2 = \frac {z_3 + z_4} 2$ from the parallelogram condition.

From Vieta $z_1+ z_2+ z_3+ z_4=4$ therefore $z_1 + z_2 = z_3 + z_4 = 2$.

Also from Vieta $z_1z_2 + z_1z_3 + z_1z_4 + z_2z_3 + z_2z_4 + z_3z_4=3-2i$ equivalent $z_1 (z_3 + z_4) + z_2(z_3 + z_4) + z_3z_4 + z_1z_2=3-2i$ equivalent $4 + z_3z_4 + z_1z_2 = 3-2i \tag 1$
Now, also from Vieta $z_1z_2z_3z_4=6-8i \tag2$

Let $z_1z_2 = a$ and $z_3z_4=b$. From (1) and (2)

$a + b = -1 -2i, ab=6-8i$. Should be easy to continue from here.